# What is a "subpath pattern" in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, module, node-modules

While reading a [blog](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3629473/whats-new-in-angular-13.html) about what's new in Angular 13, I've encountered the following statement:

> Node.js versions older than v12.20 are no longer supported, due to Angular packages using the **Node.js package exports feature with subpath patterns**.

So, I wounder, what does it means "subpath patterns"? The examples will be more than welcome here.

Answer (score 9):

I quote from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns):

## Subpath patterns

*Added in: v14.13.0, v12.20.0*

For packages with a small number of exports or imports, we recommend explicitly listing each exports subpath entry. But for packages that have large numbers of subpaths, this might cause `package.json` bloat and maintenance issues.

For these use cases, subpath export patterns can be used instead:

```
// ./node_modules/es-module-package/package.json
{
  "exports": {
    "./features/*": "./src/features/*.js"
  },
  "imports": {
    "#internal/*": "./src/internal/*.js"
  }
}
```

**`*` maps expose nested subpaths as it is a string replacement syntax only.**

All instances of `*` on the right hand side will then be replaced with this value, including if it contains any / separators.

```
import featureX from 'es-module-package/features/x';
// Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/features/x.js

import featureY from 'es-module-package/features/y/y';
// Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/features/y/y.js

import internalZ from '#internal/z';
// Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/internal/z.js
```

This is a direct static replacement without any special handling for file extensions. In the previous example, `pkg/features/x.json` would be resolved to `./src/features/x.json.js` in the mapping.

The property of exports being statically enumerable is maintained with exports patterns since the individual exports for a package can be determined by treating the right hand side target pattern as a `**` glob against the list of files within the package. Because `node_modules` paths are forbidden in exports targets, this expansion is dependent on only the files of the package itself.

To exclude private subfolders from patterns, `null` targets can be used:

```
// ./node_modules/es-module-package/package.json
{
  "exports": {
    "./features/*": "./src/features/*.js",
    "./features/private-internal/*": null
  }
}
```

```
import featureInternal from 'es-module-package/features/private-internal/m';
// Throws: ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED

import featureX from 'es-module-package/features/x';
// Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/features/x.js
```

---

### Update (2023 Aug 15)

##### response to [cmcdragonkai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582917/cmcdragonkai) comment, quote from [Medium](https://betterprogramming.pub/the-native-way-to-configure-path-aliases-in-frontend-projects-5db70f19a6e0) (Maksim Zemskov):

To configure path aliases, you can add a few lines to `package.json` as described in the documentation. For instance, if you want to allow imports relative to the `src` directory, add the following imports field to `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-awesome-project",
    "imports": {
        "#*": "./src/*"
    }
}
```

To use the configured alias, imports can be written like this:

```
import { apiClient } from '#shared/api';
import { ProductView } from '#entities/product/components/ProductView';
import { addProductToCart } from '#features/add-to-cart/actions';
```

Comment: It appears that `.` is a valid export key. However `#` is not a valid import key. Why did they allow `.` but not `#`? What if I wanted to do something like `import X from '#';`?

Comment: why you wanna do that? what is the use case ? @CMCDragonkai

Comment: Turns out nodejs allows you to do self-reference now, so no need. What I actually need is a way to entirely bypass subpath exports/imports rules for packages that are misconfigured.

Comment: I updated the answer. hope it help with your case. @CMCDragonkai

Comment: Cool but also you can also do `import x from 'my-awesome-project';` now too. https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_self_referencing_a_package_using_its_name